# Find files belonging to a group

Tags: files, permissions, find, group

Actually I want to find all the files and folders that are under the same group, 
for example I have this :

```
[test]     user1/sam
a.txt      user9/sam
b.txt      user4/sam
```

I'm looking for a command that show me, all files and folders under the same group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using GNU find, you can search for all directories and files that belong to groupX:

```
find / -group groupX
```

From `man find`:

```
   -group gname
          File belongs to group gname (numeric group ID allowed).
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the `ls` command with the `-l` (long format) option and the `-G` (group) option, this command will list all files and folders in the current directory with their respective group information.

for example

```
ls -lG | grep "group_name"
```